# Does the phrase "fully n percent" have real meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

For example:

> Fully 46 percent of the recipients polled in the social sciences
>   had...

Is this simply a way to avoid starting the sentence with a number? As in:

> Forty-six percent...

I understand that, mathematically speaking, percents can be fractional.  In the context of this example - and many others that I've seen - it just seems superfluous.

Comment: It's an intensifier, an adverb meant to make the figure "46 percent" seem more significant. To make it seem less significant, a  copywriter or political spin doctor would substitute *barely* for *fully*.

Comment: You can look up the definintion of ["fully" in Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fully?q=fully), where it says that it means *no less or fewer than* and that it is used to emphasise an amount.

Comment: So in other words, it functions the same way as "a whopping".

Comment: @Robusto: That's a slightly cynical way of putting it. Oftentimes the writer could reasonably assume many of his readers will be completely unaware that x% *really is a lot* in the context of whatever is being written about. Prefacing the actual value with **fully** or **a mere** is a useful shorthand way of bringing them up to speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does have a formal meaning, similar to *literally*.  A claim that '10 per cent of the respondents did this' might mean 9.5%, or, in everyday speech, anything above 7-8%.  *Fully ten per cent* is emphasizing that the writer means no less than a full ten per cent (perhaps slightly more). Just like *literally*, however, the temptation to use the word simply as an intensifier has proved too strong in many cases; judge for yourself whether the writer is sufficiently numerate (and scrupulous) to use the proper meaning or not.

Comment: I don't agree that *"fully 10%"* guarantees the actual value isn't really 9.8%. What it normally means, as Hellion says, is that the value is more than people who take an interest in such figures might have expected.

Comment: @Fumble: are you referring to what most people intend by the phrase, or the literal meaning of the words?  The two are different, as I said: my answer meant only the latter.

Comment: I mean this usage of "fully" is idiomatic, and means "surprisingly high" rather than "at least, not a fraction less". Imho *"a full 10%"* is a related expression that can convey *either* of those two nuances. But if I read that my car's fuel-tank holds *"a full 70 litres"* I expect that to be 15.4 gallons (not 15 gallons, which is only 68.2 litres).

Answer (score 3):

As the comments say, *Fully* is being used as an intensifier here, to make the number 'feel big'.  That is, its goal is to give you the impression of "wow, that's a lot," or at least "that's more than you would have expected".